# Simple parallax, CSS Layers, reveal last section when scrolling

Tags: css

I've been seeing a really cool effect recently in the web world. It's the 'layered look'. A user will scroll down the page and the last section will come out under the first few sections of the page. Sometimes it's with an image, but I've found that content can be displayed like this as well.

Now, I'm well familiar with `z-index` and CSS positioning.

However, I can't seem to get the right combination to make it work the way I would like.

HTML:

```
<div id="main">Content content content content content content</div>
<div id="revealed-section"></div>
```

So `#main` would appear as if it's on top of `#revealed-section`, and once the user scrolls down to a certain point `#reveal-section` slides out.

I've done many searches, but I don't know the term for this technique.

Any ideas? I'd prefer a CSS only solution.

---

**Here!:** http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/338_parallax/src/index.html
I want the transition from slide 3 to 4, but it has to be with content rather than just a background image.

I've found that I also want a footer that looks as if it's initially attached to `#main`, but when the user scrolls further down, `#revealed-section` "expands".

One way to do this I'm guessing would be to affix the footer at the bottom of the screen at a certain point. Any tips?

Comment: Are you talking about parallex scrolling feature as in boy-coy.com?

Comment: Sort of...I don't really need the items to float. It's more like http://alleynyc.com but the revealed section would be at the bottom rather than the top of the screen

Answer (score 2):

The revealed section can be made `position:fixed`. The placeholder should have a set height, just to extend the page so the user can scroll down and see the revealed fixed div.

HTML

```
<div id="main">Content content content content content content</div>
<div id="revealed-section-placeholder"></div>
<div id="revealed-section"> Content here </div>
```

CSS

```
#main {position:relative; z-index: 1;} 
#revealed-section {position:fixed; bottom: 0;}
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/qYbs7/1/

Comment: Okay, let's adapt the situation a bit. There's a footer below the revealed content. And when the user gets to the footer, it appears that's all that is left. But they can keep scrolling and `#revealed-content` is shown on scroll. In other words, `#revealed-section-placeholder`'s height increases on scroll.

Comment: Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/xa3Dx/2/

I want the footer to stick to the bottom on the page once it appears. That way it can look like `revealed-section` is expanding.