# Parallax Scrolling between sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to emulate the scrolling effect on http://theoneandonlyboutique.com/

Notice how when you scroll the bottom section overlays the top section as it fades. Currently my code is simple. The layout is separated between sections.

```
<section class="red">Section 1</section>
<section class="green">Section 2</section>
<section class="orange">Section 3</section>
```

and the css:

```
section {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kfhnj8ep/

This was the closest I found on stackoverflow [Simple parallax, CSS Layers, reveal last section when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179170/simple-parallax-css-layers-reveal-last-section-when-scrolling)

Any tips/help would be great! Think this helps users focus on the content at hand.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to have an image or whatever you want to animate inside one of your sections which you will move using javascript while scrolling.

Something like this:

```
var cover = document.querySelector('.js-parallax'),
  coverHeight = Math.round(cover.offsetHeight),
  translate = 0,
  parallaxThreshold = 3; // parallax speed

function parallax() {
  if (window.scrollY < coverHeight) {
    translate = Math.round(window.scrollY / parallaxThreshold);
    cover.style.transform = 'translateY(' + translate + 'px)';
  }
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(parallax);

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(parallax);
}, false);
```

I’ve made a demo here where you can check out the full code: http://codepen.io/vincentorback/pen/MYYrmj